# Install CloudFlare to my home network?

Tags: home-networking

I want to make my home network DDoS protected with CloudFlare. Is this possible?

I'm using the D-Link DIR-655 router with Comcast internet.

Comment: Is there a reason that you'd have a higher chance for getting a DDOS attack on a home network?

Comment: I do a lot of deals with people on forums. Generally, if they feel like something went wrong (such as the service not working, etc) they just DDoS and charge me back on paypal instead of talking it out

Comment: Can you roll your IP by power-cycling the modem? That's what I'd do.

Comment: I can do that, but I'd prefer to protect myself permanently.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFlare can only proxy web traffic for an actual domain.